# Force custom filter to work in repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to use filter in my loop.
Let's say that we have simple array with names: `['Thomas', 'Brian', 'Joana']`. I want to view filtered set of names. It works as expected when I use Angular's filter:

```
<input ng-model="filterText" />
<span ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filterText">{{name}}</span>
```

but when I want to use some custom filter method it doesn't work when value of 'filterText' input is changed:

```
<input ng-model="filterText" />
<span ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filterMethod">{{name}}</span>
```

In js file:

```
$scope.filterMethod = function(item) {
  if ($scope.textFilter==item || $scope.textFilter==null) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I want to force filtering action on list of names alway when user change 'filterText' input, but actually this list is changed only if it is filtered by Angular predefined filter. Complete plnkr example: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HMvLCJi1xp23468pv6Ip?p=preview)

Comment: The variable that you use as ng-model doesn't match to what you are using in filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the custom filter like this

```
$scope.filterMethod = function(name) {
    return function(item){  
      if(!name ) return item;

      if (name && item.startsWith(name)) {
        return item;
      } 
   }
}
```

and change call the filter in the html like this

```
<span ng-repeat="name in result = (names | filter:filterMethod(filterText))">
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.names = ['Thomas', 'Brian', 'Joana'];

$scope.filterMethod = function(name) {
 return function(item){  
  if(!name ) return item;
  
  if (name && item.startsWith(name)) {
    return item;
  } 
 }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input ng-model="filterText" />
 <span ng-repeat="name in result = (names | filter:filterMethod(filterText))">
 {{name}}
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need custom filter:

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(items, searchText) {
    var filtered = [];
    //logic
    return filtered;
  }
});

<span ng-repeat="name in names | customFilter:text">{{name}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.textFilter` to `$scope.filterText`

```
$scope.filterMethod = function(item) {
  if ($scope.textFilter==item || $scope.textFilter==null) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is a fork to your plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/a3uSyez0VFGbZ5ZARcu7?p=preview